Command Prompt not loading for Telnet in GNS3
I am having issues using GNS3 on macbook pro m1. I have tried to set up a basic topology connecting IOS router 7200 with VPCS labeled PC1 and PC2. The issues comes from after starting all devices and clicking terminal the only one that loads is my R1. I get the R1# command prompt but my PC1 and PC2 are stuck on
{mycommandusername}% echo -n -e "\033]0;PC1\007"; clear; PATH='/Applications/GNS3.app/Contents/MacOS:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin' telnet localhost 5006 ; exit

Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.

Ive tried a lot of things from deleting and redownloading to trying different terminals like iTerm2 3.x etc... I have also tried to use a Ubuntu vm that. I setup using VMware Fusion. I should preface I am new to the software so my expertise is not extensive nor am I confident I worded this well. I have also tried other forums but no one has gotten back to me yet. Is this issue just common with macOS and is it just not compatible? any advise is welcomed.
I have tried setting up tinycore in VMware Fusion to use in my GNS3 but that did not load so I tried Ubuntu and got the vm to work but it wasnt working in my GNS3. I have also redownloaded and downloaded again. Additionally tried to use iTerm2 3.x, I have also just tried waiting for it to do something.

Basically version 2.2.45 is the last one where vpcs seem to work. No ideia why tho, just download the .dmg from their github https://github.com/gns3/gns3-gui/releases?page=1
If something else doesn't work just try an even older version i guess.
